# Adding value to a datatable to the second column

Tags: c#, datatable

How can I add value from listbox2 to a second column "Date"? The code works, but it adds values to the first column "Name".

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(cesta);
XmlNodeType type;

DataSet dsload = new DataSet();
dsload.ReadXml(cesta);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));

while (reader.Read())
{  
   if (reader.Name == "Name")
    {
        reader.Read();
        listbox1.Items.Add(reader.Value);
    }

    if (reader.Name == "Date")
    {
        reader.Read();
        listbox2.Items.Add(reader.Value);
    }

}

foreach (string value in listbox1.Items)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = value;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
data.DataSource = dt;

foreach (string value in listbox2.Items)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = value;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
data.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime))); 

while (reader.Read())
{
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   //if (reader.Name == "Name")
   //{
        // reader.Read();  <-- this isn't needed, you're already reading...
        listbox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        dr["Name"] = reader[0].ToString();
   //}

   //if (reader.Name == "Date")
   //{
        listbox2.Items.Add(reader[1].ToString());
        dr["Date"] = reader[1].ToString();
   //}
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
data.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I'm with Jeremy. vote up :)

Comment: He read an xml file, a new row is added for each Element in XML File !!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string value in listbox2.Items)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[1] = value;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

change index from 0 to 1

Or a better way would be access column directly by name.

```
foreach (string value in listbox2.Items)
{
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr["Date"] = value;
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add a row for each Value of `listbox1` or `listbox2`
you can just use a  single boucle as :

```
   while (reader.Read())
    {  
       if (reader.Name == "Name")
        {
            listbox1.Items.Add(reader.Value);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = value;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        if (reader.Name == "Date")
        {
            listbox2.Items.Add(reader.Value);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Date"] = value;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }      
    }
```

If you need to add one row for both Listbox use the `Jeremy Thompson` answer